# Tengo un problema con el select

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, html-select

**Como hacer para que solo me aparezca el usuario seleccionado?**
Que al seleccionar otro usuario el anterior desaparezca y solo salga el seleccionado.

Codigo Javascript

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", true);
ajax.onreadystatechange = cargarUsuarios;
ajax.send(null);

function cargarUsuarios() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
        var datos = ajax.response;
        var users = JSON.parse(datos);

        var select = document.getElementById("select");
        var infoUser = document.getElementById("infoUser");
        var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

        users.forEach(e => {

            var options = `<option value="${e.id}"> ${e.name} </option>`;
            select.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", options);

            select.addEventListener('change', function () {
                var selectedOption = this.options[select.selectedIndex];

                if (selectedOption.value == e.id) {

                    var lista = `<li>Username: ${e.username} <hr> Calle: ${e.address.street} <hr> Movil: ${e.phone} <hr> Compañia: ${e.company.name}</li><hr>`;
                    infoUser.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', lista)

                    div.style.display = "block";

                }

            });

        });   
    }
}
```

Codigo HTML:

```
<form action="#" name="form">
    <select name="nombres" id="select">
        <option>Selecciona un usuario</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div>
   <ul id="infoUser">

   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: puedes usar jquery $("#infoUser").empty();lo que hace es eliminar todos los li a.. de tu UL....esto lo haces antes de crearlo..!!

Answer (score 0):

Agrega esta línea de código después de tu `if` para que elimine todos los hijos de tu elemento `ul`.

```
 while (infoUser.firstChild) {
      infoUser.removeChild(infoUser.firstChild);
    }
```

Comment: He probado el codigo que has puesto. Pero se borran todos los LI. Puede que me haya explicado mal. Quiero que solo se muestre la informacion del usuario seleccionado. Gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado el problema cambiando  infoUser.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', lista) por
infoUser.innerHTML = lista;